Erro de Compilação - Visual Studio Code
Escrevi um codigo pra uma atividade, que necessita de verificar os numeros de 1 a 500, que se encaixam na tripla de pitagoras (A soma dos catetos quadrados deve ser igual a hipotenusa ao quadrado). Mas o VisualStudio Code não compila os numeros que se encaixam, e eu não consigui resolver, tentei rodar pelo codeblocks, mas o resultado foi o mesmo, não sei se pode ser o codigo. Vou deixar o codigo aqui. Se alguem souber oque pode ser
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    int lado1;
    int lado2;
    int hipotenusa;
    int soma_catetos;
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    
    for (lado1 = 1; lado1 <= 500; lado1++)
    {
        for (lado2 = 1; lado2 <= 500; lado2++)
        {
            for (hipotenusa = 1; hipotenusa <= 500; hipotenusa++)
            {
                soma_catetos = pow(lado1, 2) + pow(lado2, 2);
                if (soma_catetos == pow(hipotenusa, 2))
                {
                    printf("%d² + %d² = %d²\n", lado1, lado2, hipotenusa);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


Esta pergunta já foi postada, e o espaço de comentários foi desativado nesta segunda postagem para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada). Queira editar aquela elaborando melhor, que automaticamente ela é destacada para a comunidade reavaliar.
